# Formal Correctness proof for Greedy solution for Wine trading (SPOJ)?

Tags: algorithm, greedy, proof-of-correctness

Don't get me wrong about posting a question for a problem on an online Judge. I just want to know how to prove the correctness of the solution. Following is the problem [Wine trading problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/GERGOVIA/). It says there are houses in a row at unit distance and each house either wants to sell or buy wine. The total demand = total supply. Work done in a transaction is amount of wine involved times the distance. The problem is to fulfill demand of all houses in minimum work. The proposed solution is that the first seller(say starting from right side of row) sells to the first buyer(the amount = min(seller,buyer))(This is the greedy choice) and then solve for the remaining problem. How can one formally prove this to be correct?

Comment: @user1990169 It is not a general transportation problem. Here it is linear in the sense that the points are on a line. It can make a huge difference.

Comment: As long as wine is not moved across the same interval in opposite directions (which is just easted work), all solutions have the same cost.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it is as formal as you want it, but here is an intuition of proof.

To simplify I will note the suppliers as '+' and the others as '-'.

WLOG, I will start with a supplier at the left side. So you have the choice of the buyer.

```
+         -    -
```

Suppose you didn't choose the first one.

```
+         -    -
<==============>
```

Then you have to feed the first one by another supplier, and the only reason you could have chosen him is that he is closer to the first buyer. He can be at the left or at the right of the first buyer.

LEFT

```
+      +  -    -
<==============>
       <==>
```

Well, the distance is exactly the same as with the greedy solution.

```
+      +  -    -
<=========>
       <=======>
```

RIGHT

```
+         - +  -
<==============>
          <=>
```

Well, the greedy solution would be better (since it avoids overlapping).

```
+         - +  -
<=========>
            <==>
```

In other words, greedy overlaps only when necessary, and if not, it benefits from 2 times the overlapping distance.

Comment: I guess you can use the same idea when assuming there are several '+' or '-' at the very same place.